# queryset.update is not working in for loop

Tags: django, django-admin-actions

I want to change the name for any database variable if its match abc.

```
def icall(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    for pri in queryset:
        print('from test:', pri.name, pri.title) # priting if working fine
        if pri.name == 'abc':        # loop is matching the condition
            pri.update(name='zzz')  ## the value is not getting update in DB
        else:                                      
            print("gg not mached")
```

the `pri.update(name='zzz')` os not working here.

can someone please help me to know the correct statement to update the database based on the if else condition.

Comment: Please look into this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#conditional-update

Answer (score 2):

```
def icall(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    for pri in queryset:
        print('from test:', pri.name, pri.title)
        if pri.name == 'abc':
            pri.name ='zzz'
            pri.save()
            print("working")
        else:
            print("gg not mached")
```

Answer (score 1):

Update query is done on a queryset. It is not done on a single object like you are trying to do. You can simply do

```
queryset.filter(name='abc').update(name='zzz')
```

Comment: I dont think you need queryset.objects.filter, simply queryset.filter would be enough

Answer (score 0):

You cannot update a single object using the update query. Can update objects in a queryset as a whole using update. Please refer the document for clarification: [Django Update query](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once)

In your case. You can do:

```
queryset.filter(name='abc').update(name='zzz')
```

instead of the for-loop.

OR

```
for pri in queryset:
    if pri.name == 'abc':        # loop is matching the condition
        pri.name='zzz'
        pri.save() # save the updated value
```

This is in case you have signals attached to your models. The Update query does not actually use django save and consequently does not emit pre_save,  post_save signals.

Comment: perfect is there any way to match queryset.filter(name='abc') in if condition?

Comment: if queryset.filter(name == 'abc'):
      then : do something 
 if queryset.filter(name == 'def'):
      then : do something

Comment: "do something"...is it updating fields?

Comment: Yes you can do that.

Comment: if re.match(regex, content) is not None:
  blah..

got it :)

Comment: Please mark upvote the answer if it helped to find the solution t your question ;)